# Devise CRUD validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, devise

Problem: I want to make `password` & `password_confirmation` fields `validates presence:true` for `create` action and no validation for `update` action

guest.rb:

```
class Guest < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable
  validates :email, presence: true
end
```

My guests_controller.rb:

```
class GuestsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_guest, only: [:show, :edit, :update]

  def index
    @guests = Guest.all
  end

  def show
    @guest =  Guest.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @guest = Guest.new
  end

  def edit
    @guest = Guest.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html do
          @guest = Guest.new(guest_params)
          if @guest.save
            redirect_to guests_path, notice: 'Client was successfully created.'
          else
            render :new
          end
        end
      end
  end

  def update
    @guest = Guest.find(params[:id])
    if @guest.update_attributes(guest_params)
      sign_in(@guest, :bypass => true) if @guest == current_guest
      redirect_to guests_path, notice: 'Client was successfully updated.'
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end
```

If I put `validates :password, presence: true`, it effects everything, whereas I need it only for `create`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [Active Record Validations Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html):

> The `:on` option lets you specify when the validation should happen. The default behavior for all the built-in validation helpers is to be run on save (both when you're creating a new record and when you're updating it). If you want to change it, you can use on: `:create` to run the validation only when a new record is created or `on: :update` to run the validation only when a record is updated.

So in your case you would use:

```
validates :email, presence: true, on: :create
```

I suggest you take a moment to sit down and read through the entire guide and [the API documentation for `validates`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates).